# How to calculate initial bearing on Great Circle Distance Method?

Tags: javascript

I want calculate initial bearing from point A to point B on Great Circle Method. The prototype of javascript that I got from website like this :

```
var y = Math.sin(λ2-λ1) * Math.cos(φ2);
var x = Math.cos(φ1)*Math.sin(φ2) -
Math.sin(φ1)*Math.cos(φ2)*Math.cos(λ2-λ1);
var brng = Math.atan2(y, x).toDegrees();
```

**Where :
λ = longtitude
φ = latitude**

So I try it to my HTML like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

```
<script>

    function bearing() 
    {

        if (typeof(Number.prototype.toDegrees) === "undefined") 
        {
            Number.prototype.toDegrees = function() 
            {
                return this * 180 / Math.PI;
            }
        }

        var getlat1 = document.getElementById("lat1").value;
        var getlong1 = document.getElementById("long1").value;
        var getlat2 = document.getElementById("lat2").value;
        var getlong2 = document.getElementById("long2").value;

        var lat1 = parseFloat(getlat1);
        var long1 = parseFloat(getlong1);
        var lat2 = parseFloat(getlat2);
        var long2 = parseFloat(getlong2);

        var y = Math.sin(long2-long1) * Math.cos(lat2);
        var x = Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2) -
        Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2)*Math.cos(long2-long1);
        var brng = Math.atan2(y, x).toDegrees();

        document.getElementById('bearing').innerHTML = brng;
        return brng;
    }

</script>

</head>
```

```
<form action="#" onsubmit="bearing(); return false;">
  <p>
    Location 1 :
    <input type="text" name="lat1" id="lat1" size="40" />
    <input type="text" name="long1" id="long1" size="40" />
  </p>
  <p>
    Location 2 :
    <input type="text" name="lat2" id="lat2" size="40" />
    <input type="text" name="long2" id="long2" size="40" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="find" value="Search" />
  </p>
</form>
Distance : <p id="results"></p>
<br />
Bearing : <p id="bearing"></p>
```

**My input for Location 1 => latitude = -7.2742174 & longtitude = 112.719087 and
My input for Location 2 => latitude = -7.586675 & longtitude = 112.8082266**

But the problem is, the result on my page is 175.63821414343275. Besides, the right answer is 164.21.
Anyone, do you know what's my mistake on my program? Thanks..

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It appears you haven't converted the arguments to radians.